# Question on notation: Using Conditional Sums to express the total distance traveled by a moving body with position $x=x(t)$

Tags: notation

**This is a question on notation**

Can I express the total distance $s=s(t_1,t_2)$ that a moving body has traveled using the following (conditional) sum?

$$s(t_1,t_2) = \sum_{\forall [t_a,t_b] \subseteq [t_1, t_2]: x'(t) \neq 0} \big |x(t_a) - x(t_b) \big |$$

Note that the total space travelled is given by the summation of the absolute values of the displacements for every subspace of $[t_1,t_2]$ that the velocity has a constant sign.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The presented notation (what is written under the $\sum$) is not standard, not self-explaining, and does not reflect your intention. What you mean is the following (it cannot be done without text): One has
$$s(t_1,t_2)=\sum_{k=1}^N|x(\tau_k)-x(\tau_{k-1})|$$
for any partition $${\cal P}:\quad t_1=\tau_0<\tau_1<\ldots<\tau_N=t_2$$
with $x'$ semidefinite on each subinterval $[\tau_{k-1},\tau_k]$.

Here it was tacitly assumed (as in your question) that $t\mapsto x(t)$ is real- (not vector-) valued.

Comment: Yes it's algebraic; not vector. Otherwise I would have written $\vec x = \vec x(t)$